# How to handle messages from multiple windows

Tags: c++, winapi

So I have multiple windows running and I'd like to handle the messages for all of them so they do not hang. I have tried multiple things so far:

1) Making it into a thread (kind of stupid but I tried):

```
auto ProcessThread(
    std::vector<HWND> Windows
) -> void
{
    for (;;)
    {
        MSG Msg1 = decltype(Msg1){0x00};
        MSG Msg2 = decltype(Msg2){0x00};

        GetMessageW(&Msg1, Windows.at(0), 0, 0);
        GetMessageW(&Msg2, Windows.at(1), 0, 0);

        TranslateMessage(&Msg1);
        TranslateMessage(&Msg2);

        DispatchMessageW(&Msg1);
        DispatchMessageW(&Msg2);
    }

    return;
}

...

    std::vector<HWND> Windows = { lpScreen.m_WindowHandle, lpPopup.m_WindowHandle };
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(ProcessThread),
        &Windows, 0, nullptr);

    while (WAIT_TIMEOUT == WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 1000)) {}

    CloseHandle(hThread);
```

2) Just cramming a second message loop

```
    MSG Msg1 = decltype(Msg1){0x00};
    MSG Msg2 = decltype(Msg2){0x00};

    while (GetMessageW(&Msg1, Hwnd1, 0, 0) && GetMessageW(&Msg2, Hwnd2, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg1);
        TranslateMessage(&Msg2);

        DispatchMessageW(&Msg1);
        DispatchMessageW(&Msg2);
    }
```

3) Other variations of the second

---

So far all of them made my windows unmovable and gave me that loading cursor.

Any ideas?

Comment: Considering that [`GetMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage) *blocks* the second alternative is a little flawed.

Comment: Yeah man Ive no idea what to do, a bit sleep deprived as well. What would you do?

Comment: To receive messages for all windows, simply don't filter. To understand why that code is broken, see [The dangers of filtering window messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050209-00/?p=36493).

Comment: So how do I prevent it from being stuck then if I remove it?

Comment: I don't understand what *"it"* is or what *"prevent from being stuck"* is supposed to mean. You certainly want your message loop to dispatch *all* messages, for all windows, as well as thread messages (`WM_QUIT` is a prominent example of the latter). If you need a non-blocking version of `GetMessage`, use `PeekMessage`, or [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjects) if you need to wait on other waitable objects.

Comment: The standard, simple message loop found in all beginner tutorials services multiple windows. If you want help with a problem in your code, you must first make it clear what that problem is. Since the rest of us happily manage apps with multiple windows, clearly you are doing something different. But what?

Comment: The fact that you are sleep deprived is irrelevant to us, and in fact casts your question in a poor light. We aren't here to give personal one to one support for people why aren't managing their time and deadlines. If you can't find time to sleep (or indeed learn the basics of Win32 GUI programming) then that's your problem, not ours. This is a site for questions that will prove useful to other visitors. Read what you posted again and ask yourself if you believe it fits that description. Other useful resources for you: [help] and [tour].

Comment: Well the original post contains the actual question

Comment: I recommended (twice) to you in [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55858281/62576) that you find a good book on WinAPI programming, because it's fairly apparent that you're just throwing up Hail Mary's and hoping things work. I still recommend one of Petzold's books (even the older ones) as a good starting place.

Comment: You should use `GetMessageW(&Msg1, 0, 0, 0)`, as most guides do. Other forms should be used only if you want to pick one specific message (with given code or range of codes) and you know that it is here. If you are not sure it is better to use `PeekMessage`.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm just specifically bad in windows since every time I made one Id just C&p and just tweak a bit based on intuition. I will go specifically look up windows and how they work

Comment: @DanielSęk That does not work for both forms no matter how I write it. I will research more before trying

Comment: *Intuition* isn't going to work with the WinAPI when you have no knowledge on which to base that *intuition*. Flailing around in the code isn't going to work for you, and it's unrealistic of you to expect us to keep bailing you out of the messes you're creating in your code because you don't want to take the time to learn the basics first. Amazon and eBay both have offers for Petzold's Windows programming books, and even the older ones (that are extremely inexpensive) would be better than the nothing you're depending on now..

Comment: [Get Started with Win32 and C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows), in case you don't want to spend much time or money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. `ProcessThread()` is declared all wrong for `CreateThread()`, and the compiler would normally scream at you for that, but you are using an erroneous type-cast to quiet the compiler instead of fixing the error.  As such, `ProcessThread()` will not be able to receive the `vector` correctly at runtime.  The `ProcessThread()` would need to look more like this instead:

   ```
   DWORD WINAPI ProcessThread(LPVOID lpParam)
   {
       std::vector<HWND> *Windows = static_cast<std::vector<HWND>*>(lpParam);
       ...
       return 0;
   }

   ...

   HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(..., &ProcessThread, &Windows, ...);
   ```
2. your thread's message loop is all wrong.  Call `GetMessage()` ONCE per loop iteration, and do not specify any filtering `HWND` at all (see [The dangers of filtering window messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050209-00/?p=36493)).  It will pull the next available message from the message queue, which you can then pass to `DispatchMessage()` to send the message along to the appropriate `WndProc` for further processing.

   ```
   DWORD WINAPI ProcessThread(LPVOID lpParam)
   {
       std::vector<HWND> *Windows = static_cast<std::vector<HWND>*>(lpParam);
       MSG Msg;

       while (GetMessageW(&Msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
       {
           TranslateMessage(&Msg);
           DispatchMessageW(&Msg);
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```
3. You are creating a worker thread just to wait for it to terminate, without doing anything else in parallel.  That makes the worker thread completely useless.  You need to get rid of that thread, especially given that...
4. ... you are running your message loop in a separate thread than the one that creates the windows.  You can't do that at all!  A window has *thread affinity*.  `(Get|Peek)Message()` receives messages only for windows associated with the calling thread, so only the thread that creates a window can receive messages for that window.

You are over-thinking your code design.  You can greatly simplify it to this:

```
std::vector<HWND> Windows = { lpScreen.m_WindowHandle, lpPopup.m_WindowHandle };
MSG Msg;

while (GetMessageW(&Msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
    DispatchMessageW(&Msg);
}
```

If `lpScreen.m_WindowHandle` and `lpPopup.m_WindowHandle` are the only windows available in the calling thread, then you don't even need the `vector` at all!

However, if you are interested in processing messages only for specific windows, this does present an issue.  The code above will receive messages for ALL windows in the calling thread.  If that is not what you want, then you COULD (but shouldn't!) filter for specific windows in the `vector`, eg:

```
std::vector<HWND> Windows = { lpScreen.m_WindowHandle, lpPopup.m_WindowHandle };
MSG Msg;

for(auto h : Windows)
{
    while (PeekMessageW(&Msg, h, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&Msg);
    }
}
```

But that can lead to message starvation for other windows, if you are not careful.

Otherwise, you would just have to use a separate thread to CREATE AND PROCESS just the windows you are interested in.